# How openSource projects are managed?

Tags: uml, scrum, methodology

actually I'm having Software Engineering classe, and we are trying to learn steps to make a good software. We are talking about UML, Scrum etc ... and I'm wondering how open source projects (like linux, firefox, apache, gnome, ...) are managed and what kind of system and methods are used to have a good software ?

thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fast google gave me these simple wiki pages:

[Open_source_software_development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source_software_development)

[Open_source_software_assessment_methodologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source_software_assessment_methodologies)

I think this will give you a start. I hope this helps you.